# Method reference in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

```
public class Car {

    private int maxSpeed;

    public Car(int maxSpeed) {
        this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    }

    public int getMaxSpeed() {
        return maxSpeed;
    }
}
```

We can sort a list of cars by,

```
    Car carX = new Car(155);
    Car carY = new Car(140);

    List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
    cars.add(carX);
    cars.add(carY);

    cars.sort(Comparator.comparing(Car::getMaxSpeed));
```

If we see the signature of the method `Comparator.comparing`, the input parameter type is `Function<? super T, ? extends U>`

In the above example, how is `Car::getMaxSpeed` being cast to `Function<? super T, ? extends U>` while the following does not compile?

> ```
>   Function<Void, Integer> function = Car::getMaxSpeed;
> ```

Comment: What is the compiler error?

Comment: The error is `Cannot resolve method`. I tried both, Car::getMaxSpeed and carX::getMaxSpeed

Comment: I copy/paste your code, it works on my side, it seems to be an IDE issue

Comment: Please edit that information into your question.

Comment: I don't have any error with Eclipse Mars.2 and JDK 1.8.0_51. As a side-note, you can use `Comparator.comparingInt` to avoid boxing.

Comment: I don't think Void can be used as a type parameter in java.

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding here. Your original question was about `carX::getMaxSpeed` which is very different than `Car::getMaxSpeed`. Most answers talk about the first revision, not all. This is confusing: your edit invalidated part of the answers...

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful: you *can* declare a parameter of type `Void`, that is, expecting an instance of `java.lang.Void`, but you are unlikely to ever see something other than `null` there, so it’s not much useful. The point is, `Void` is *not* a wrapper type for `void`, it’s only a placeholder for `Void.TYPE` which holds the `Class` object representing `void.class`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is because the `getMaxSpeed` method is a `Function<Car, Integer>`.

Namely:

```
<Car, Integer> Comparator<Car> java.util.Comparator.comparing(
    Function<? super Car, ? extends Integer> keyExtractor
)
```

**Note**

In order to reference `getMaxSpeed` from an instance of `Car` with the `::` idiom, you would have to declare a `Car` method with signature: `getMaxSpeed(Car car)`.

Comment: But OP is asking about `carX::getMaxSpeed`, not `Car::getMaxSpeed`, i.e. a method already bound to an instance.

Comment: although getMaxSpeed() does not take in a parameter, it is being cast to `Function<Car, Integer>` ?

Comment: If `getMaxSpeed` is a member function then to use Car::getMaxSpeed, `Car` would have to declare a member function `getMaxSpeed()` (no parameters)  or a static function `getMaxSpeed(Car)`

Comment: @saravana_pc Method references to instance methods, when written like that, add the receiver as the first parameter.  `Car::getMaxSpeed` is equivalent to `car -> car.getMaxSpeed()`.

Comment: @saravana_pc This comment doesn't add much to the conversation, but I think there's a simpler way to explain this: How does "getMaxSpeed" knows which car's speed has to be returned? If you want a ref to a method that "takes a void" and returns its speed... well, that doesn't make sense, type error right there. Which car should it use? When you write "new Car().getMaxSpeed()", the function definitely knows which car should be used. Car::getMaxSpeed does not.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to create a method reference for a method that takes no parameters, such as a method already bound to an instance, you should use a `Supplier`, not a `Function`:

```
Function<Car, Integer> f1 = Car::getMaxSpeed;

Car carx = new Car(42);
Supplier<Integer> f2 = carx::getMaxSpeed;
```

In the method reference `carX::getMaxSpeed`, the "implicit" `this`-parameter of the function is already bound to `carx`, so you are left with a no-parameter-function (which, by the way, can not be used in a `Comparator`), and in Java 8, a no-parameter-function is just a `Supplier`.

Similarly, if you have a method that returns `void`, you end up with a `Comsumer`:

```
Consumer<Integer> f3 = carx::setMaxSpeed;
```

Comment: I agree. The problem is then that you can't use it in a `Comparator.comparing` invocation. **edit** that's probably *not* a problem given the context, actually.

Answer (score 4):

A member function with no parameters actually has a hidden parameter, the `this` reference. Method references of the form `ClassName::memberFunction` always use the first parameter of the functional type for the class instance, i.e. the instance's hidden `this` parameter.  So, in the case of `Car.getMaxSpeed()`, internally it has the same parameters as a `static Integer getMaxSpeed(Car car)`. `Car::getMaxSpeed` would therefore fit the functional type `Function<Car,Integer>`, just as a `static Integer getMaxSpeed(Car car)` would.

Something similar happens with member functions that take one parameter--they fit the `BiFunction` functional type, with the first parameter being the class instance.

Answer (score 2):

The assignment:

```
Function<Void, Integer> function = carX::getMaxSpeed;
```

does not compile because it's a `Supplier<Integer>`, not a `Function`.

So then, why does this compile?:

```
Comparator.comparing(Car::getMaxSpeed)
```

Java 8 allows an instance method reference that is a `Supplier<U>` to be provided where a `Function<T, U>` is expected, and the compiler effectively converts the getter method into a function.

To find out why this is possible, let's look at how we invoke a getter method using reflection:

```
System.out.println(Car.class.getMethod("getMaxSpeed").invoke(carX)); // "155"
```

When calling `invoke()` on an instance method, we pass the instance to the `invoke()` method of the getter's `Method` - there's an implied parameter of the instance type. When looked at it this way, we see that under the hood a getter is really implemented as a `Function<T, U>` via the `invoke()` method.

Comment: reference or example for the last statement?

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful The OP's own code is an example. The getter method is a supplier, but the `Comparator.comparing()` is expecting a `Function`. When the supplier method's instance type matches the expected function's parameter type, the supplier method is accepted as a function.

Comment: according to vampires answer that's not true. Or atleast not a conclusive example.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful the code in vampire's answer doesn't even compile: `Car::getMaxSpeed()` is not a valid java expression, let alone a `Function<Car, Integer>` . Same for `carX::getMaxSpeed()`. IMHO, there's nothing actually useful, let alone true, in his answer.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/22516423/1743880 and [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516331/whats-the-difference-between-instance-method-reference-types-in-java-8#comment34263784_22516423) by Stuart Marks. This answer is correct.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful See edited answer with reflection mechanics of why it works.

Comment: This has nothing to do with suppliers, and java can't magically cast from supplier to function. But UnaryOperator extends function and thus is compatible.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful if you believe that, then perhaps *you* can provide an explanation of why `Comparator.comparing(Car::getMaxSpeed)` compiles, given that `getMaxSpeed()` is not a `Function<Car, Integer>`.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful It seems that [Hank_D's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37618524/256196) says essentially the same thing as this answer.

Comment: It’s not correct to say “*it’s a*” `Supplier<Integer>`, as method references have no type of their own. `carX::getMaxSpeed` *is compatible* with a `Supplier<Integer>` and may be used where a `Supplier<Integer>` is expected. But it could also be used where a `Callable<Integer>` or an `IntSupplier` is expected. These interfaces have the same functional signature, but are otherwise unrelated.

Comment: Further, the Reflection example is misleading as `Method.invoke` has two distinct parameters for the receiver and the arguments, hence, you need pass `null` as first argument when invoking a `static` method. Also, `Method.invoke` is not involved in the process at all. If you want to peek into it, [`MethodHandle`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html) make no distinction between receiver and parameters and are indeed used under the hood to specify the target method.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) in detail:

```
Interface Function<T,R> {

    default <V> Function<T,V>   andThen(Function<? super R,? extends V> after){}

    R   apply(T t);

    default <V> Function<V,R>   compose(Function<? super V,? extends T> before){}

    static <T> Function<T,T>    identity();

}
```

note the `R apply(T t);` [Applies this function to the given argument.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#apply-T-)

```
Function<Void, Integer> function = Void::?????;
Void voidInstance = null;
function.apply(voidInstance);
```

This doesn't make sense. You want to pass a Void so that the function of the Void is applied ?

A few illustrative examples of what compiles as a function

note that `c->c.getMaxSpeed()` and `Car::getMaxSpeed` are syntactically equivalent if the method is an instanceMethod. For non-static-methods the first argument is infered from the type who's method is used, and needs to be provided later (as the instance which the method will be executed on/applied on).

```
public class Car {

    private int maxSpeed;

    public Car(int maxSpeed) {
        this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    }

    public int getMaxSpeed() {
        return this.maxSpeed;
    }
    public Void setMaxSpeed() {
        this.maxSpeed = 12;
        return null;
    }
    public static int intStaticFunction(Void v) {
        return new Random().nextInt();
    }
    public static Void voidStaticFunction(Void v) {
        return null;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Car carX = new Car(155);
        final Car carY = new Car(140);

        final List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
        cars.add(carX);
        cars.add(carY);

        cars.sort(Comparator.comparing(Car::getMaxSpeed));
        final Function<Car, Integer> function1 = c->c.getMaxSpeed();
        final Function<Car, Integer> function2 = Car::getMaxSpeed;
        final Function<Car, Void> function3 = Car::setMaxSpeed;
        final Function<Void, Void> function4 = n->n;
        final Function<Void, Integer> function5 = n->5;
        final Function<Void, Integer> function6 = Car::intStaticFunction;
        final Function<Void, Void> function7 = Car::voidStaticFunction;
        final Function<Car, Integer> function8 = function1::apply;
        final Function<Car, Integer> function9 = function2::apply;
        System.out.println(function1.apply(carX));
        System.out.println(function2.apply(carX));
        System.out.println(function8.apply(carX));
        System.out.println(function9.apply(carX));
        System.out.println(function3.apply(carX));
        System.out.println(function1.apply(carX));
        System.out.println(function2.apply(carX));
        System.out.println(function8.apply(carX));
        System.out.println(function9.apply(carX));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(function4.apply(null));
        System.out.println(function5.apply(null));
        System.out.println(function6.apply(null));
        System.out.println(function7.apply(null));
    }
}
```