# Double colon operator not working with Java

Tags: java

just trying out things in java, found following issue.

```
DefaultAndStaticMethodMain.java:8: error: not a statement
        implementation1::sendNotification;
        ^
1 error
```

Following is my code.

ParentInterface:

```
public interface ParentInterface {
    default void callForCompletion() {
        System.out.println("<<<< Notification sending completed. >>>>");
    }
}
```

Child interface:

```
public interface ChildInterface extends ParentInterface {
    public abstract void sendNotification();

    static String printNotificationSentMessage() {
        return "Notification is sent successfully.";
    }
}
```

Implementation 1:

```
public class Implementation1 implements ChildInterface {
    @Override
    public void sendNotification() {

        System.out.println("Implementation --- 1");
        System.out.println("Sending notification via email >>>");
    }
}
```

Implementation 2:

```
public class Implementation2 implements ChildInterface {
    @Override
    public void sendNotification() {
        System.out.println("Implementation ---- 2.");
        System.out.println("Sending notification via SMS >>>");
    }
}
```

Main method:

```
public class DefaultAndStaticMethodMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Implementation1 implementation1 = new Implementation1();
        implementation1::sendNotification; // Compilation error as shown above.

        Implementation2 implementation2 = new Implementation2();
        implementation2.sendNotification();

        // Following works fine.
//        Arrays.asList(implementation1, implementation2).stream().forEach(SomeInterfaceToBeRenamed::sendNotification);
    }
}
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong, I have JDK 13 installed in local machine and working with IntelliJ 2019.3 with JDK 11. I checked that IntelliJ supports JDK 13

Thanks.

**Update**
By mistake I left a semi-colon over there, removed it, please check again.

Comment: That's not valid Java, even without the errant `;`. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: What do you intend to happen from just writing a method reference by itself? If you write just `1 + 1;` you also get an error, because it's not a statement and has no effect. The error message tells you this exactly: **error: not a statement**.

Comment: may be odd number of > or < generates this issue.

Comment: "Double colon operator"? there is no such operator in java, it is a [3.11. Separators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.11)- given statement is not valid (like just having a variable alone), could be something *strange* like `((Runnable) implementation1::sendNotification).run()`, but why not just call the method?

Comment: or it could be assigned to a variable/field: `Runnable r = implementation1::sendNotification;` and executed later on `r.run();` or passed as argument to another method to be executed there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A method reference is not the same as a method call. Those are two distinct things.

- A method call is a standalone expression, or, more precisely, an *expression statement*. That means that in your case `implementation2.sendNotification()` works, as you would expect.
- A method reference, however,

  > is used to refer to the invocation of a method without actually performing the invocation

  and is not a standalone expression. It can only be used where a lambda expression can also be used. A method reference as a standalone expression does not compile, just like an arithmetic expression without assignment (e.g. `3 + 17;`). This is enforced by the Java Language Specification, [§ 14.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8) and [§ 15.13](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13).

---

**More to read:**

- [Please Explain Java 8 Method Reference to instance Method using class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32283833/please-explain-java-8-method-reference-to-instance-method-using-class-name)
- [Method reference in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618069/method-reference-in-java-8)

Answer (score 5):

What do you intend for the `implementation1::sendNotification;` line to do? Judging by the `implementation2.sendNotification();` line below it looks like you're trying to call `sendNotification` on `implementation1`, which is written like this:

```
implementation1.sendNotification();
```

The `::` notation is a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), and (as the error message says) it an identifier, not a statement, and thus can't be a line on its own. Similarly you couldn't write `implementation1;` (a variable) or `ChildInterface;` (a class identifier) as a statement.

The `.forEach(SomeInterfaceToBeRenamed::sendNotification);` line compiles because you are passing the method reference to [`forEach()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-), and *it* in turn invokes each `sendNotification()` method.