# Does BigDecimal#min method qualify as a BinaryOperator?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

The `Stream.reduce` method takes a `BinaryOperator` as an argument. The function signature of a `BinaryOperator` is `(T,T) -> T`. The `BigDecimal::min` method has only 1 parameter in its method signature (ie. `(T) -> T` ).

Why doesn't the compiler complain when I pass `BigDecimal::min` to the `Stream.reduce` method?

Sample code:

```
List<BigDecimal> bigDecimalList = new ArrayList<>();
        bigDecimalList.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(1));
        bigDecimalList.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(2));
        bigDecimalList.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(3));
BigDecimal minResult = bigDecimalList.stream().reduce(BigDecimal::min).orElse(BigDecimal.ZERO);
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'd have to guess but since `BigDecimal min(BigDecimal o)` is an instance method and thus internally the method actually has the signature `BigDecimal min(this, BigDecimal o)` it matches the requirements for `BinaryOperator`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22516331/2711488

Answer (score 19):

This is actually called *Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type*.

The compiler takes the *calling* instance as the first argument and as such these are equivalent:

```
    BinaryOperator<BigDecimal> b = (left, right) -> left.min(right);

    BinaryOperator<BigDecimal> b2 = BigDecimal::min;
    b2.apply(left, right);
```

Things are much funner IMO when you have something like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface TriFunction<A, B, C, R> {

    R apply(A a, B b, C c);

}
```

and a theoretical class:

```
class Test {

    int x;

    int y;

    public Test(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Test copy(int n, int m) {
        return new Test(m, n);
    }
}
```

Then you could write something like this:

```
  TriFunction<Test, Integer, Integer, Test> f = Test::copy;

  TriFunction<Test, Integer, Integer, Test> f2 = 
           (test, i, j) -> test.copy(i, j);
```

Comment: `n` and `m` got swapped, and it's bugging me... Great answer!

Comment: @JeffreySze if this answer helped you could accept it. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 8):

Because `BigDecimal::min` is an instance method. Javac is smart enough to turn it into a `(T, T) -> T` if you use `BigDecimal::min`. The first paramter passed to the resulting `BinaryOperator` will be the instance and the second will be the parameter of `min` (though in `BinaryOperator`'s case it is required that the order can be reversed). It will be `(T) -> T` if you use something like `new BigInteger(1)::min`.