# Example of stream reduction with distinct combiner and accumulator

Tags: java, java-stream

The question is about `java.util.stream.Stream.reduce(U identity,BiFunction<U, ? super T, U> accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner)` method.

One of the requirements is that the combiner function must be compatible with the accumulator function; for all u and t, the following must hold:

```
 combiner.apply(u, accumulator.apply(identity, t)) == accumulator.apply(u, t) (*)
```

If the `combiner` and `accumulator` are the same, the above equality is automatically true.

A `BinaryOperator` is actually extending BiFunction, therefore I can use it when `BiFunction` is required. If U and T are identical, the following is always legal:

```
operator<T> op = (x,y) -> something;

stream.reduce(id, op, op);
```

Of course, one cannot **always** use the `combiner` as `acumulator` since, in the general case, they serve for different purposes and are different Java types.

**My question**

*Is there an example of stream reduction with distinct `combiner` and `accumulator`?*

Also, I'm not interested in trivial examples, but natural examples that I can encounter in practice while doing reduction on parallel streams.

For trivial examples, there are many tutorials, like [this one](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-reduce)

**Why am I asking this question**

Basically, the reason this reduction method exists is for parallel streams. It seems to me the condition (*) is so strong that, in practice, it renders this reduction useless since rarely the reduction operations fulfill it.

Comment: Where do you draw the line between trivial and nontrivial examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here's are a few examples. Some of these may count as "trivial", particularly where there's already a function to do it for you.

### An example where `T` and `U` are the same

These are quite difficult to come up with, and are a bit contrived, as they generally involve assuming that the elements of stream and the object being accumulated have different *meanings*, even though they have the same *type*.

#### Counting

If we have a stream of integers, we could count them using `reduce`:

```java
stream.reduce(0, (count, item) -> count+1, (a, b) -> a+b);
```

Obviously, we could just use `stream.count()` here, but I'm willing to bet `count` uses the 3 argument version of `reduce` internally.

### An example where `T` and `U` are different

This gives us quite a lot of freedom, and obviously, the accumulator and combiner are never going to be the same here, as they have different types.

One of the most common ways we may want to aggregate is gathering into a collection. We *could* use `reduce` for that, but since in Java collection types are typically mutable, using `collect` will generally be more efficient. This rule applies generally: if the result type mutable, use `collect` rather than `reduce`.

#### Determining the range of a stream of numbers

```
class Range {
  static Range NONE = new Range(Double.NaN, Double.NaN);

  final double min, max;

  static Range of(double min, double max) {
    if(Double.isNaN(min) || Double.isNaN(max) || min>max) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return new Range(min, max);
  }

  private Range(double min, double max) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
  }

  boolean contains(double value) {
    return this!=Range.NONE && min<=value && max>=value;
  }

  boolean spans(Range other) {
    return this==other
      || other==Range.NONE
      || (contains(other.min) && contains(other.max));
  }

}

Range range = streamOfDoubles.reduce(
    Range.NONE,
    (range, value) -> {
      if(range==Range.NONE)
        return Range.of(value, value);
      else if(range.contains(value))
        return range;
      else
        return Range.of(Math.min(value, range.min), Math.max(value, range.max));
    },
    (a, b) -> {
      if(b.spans(a))
        return b;
      else if(a.spans(b))
        return a;
      else
        return Range.of(Math.min(a.min, b.min), Math.max(a.max, b.max));
    }
);
```

Comment: Great, the identity (*) holds!

Answer (score 4):

*If the combiner and accumulator are the same*? You are confusing things here.

`accumulator` transforms from `X` to `Y` for example (using the identity), while `combiner` merges two `Y` into one. Also notice that one is a `BiFunction` and the other one is a `BinaryOperator` (which is actually a `BiFunction<T, T, T>`).

> Is there an example of stream reduction with distinct combiner and accumulator?

These look pretty different to me:

```
    Stream.of("1", "2")
          .reduce(0, (x, y) -> x + y.length(), Integer::sum);
```

I *think* you might be confused with things like:

```
Stream.of("1", "2")
      .reduce("", String::concat, String::concat);
```

How is it possible to do?

```
BiFunction<String, String, String> bi = String::concat;
```

Well there is a [hint here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43136690/1059372).

**EDIT**

Addressing the part where "different" means different operations, `accumulator` might `sum`, while `accumulator` might `multiply`. This is exactly what the rule :

> combiner.apply(u, accumulator.apply(identity, t)) == accumulator.apply(u, t)

is about, to protected itself from two *separate* associative functions, but different operations. Let's take an example of two lists (equal, but with different order). This, btw, would be a lot funner with a `Set::of` from `java-9` that adds [an internal randomization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45352920/immutablecollections-setn-implementation-detail), so *theoretically* for the same exact input, you would get different result on the same VM from run to run. But to keep it simple:

```
List.of("a", "bb", "ccc", "dddd");
List.of("dddd", "a", "bb", "ccc");
```

And we want to perform:

```
....stream()
   .parallel()
   .reduce(0,
          (x, y) -> x + y.length(),
          (x, y) -> x * y);
```

Under the *current* implementation, this will yield the same result for *both* lists; but that is an *implementation artifact*.

There is *nothing* stopping an internal implementation in saying: "I will split the list to the smallest chunk possible, but not smaller than two elements in each of them". In such a case, this could have been translated to these splits:

```
["a",    "bb"]     ["ccc", "dddd"]
["dddd", "a" ]     ["bb" , "ccc" ]
```

Now, "accumulate" those splits:

```
0 + "a".length   = 1 ; 1 + "bb".length   = 3 // thus chunk result is 3
0 + "ccc".length = 3 ; 3 + "dddd".length = 7 // thus chunk result is 7
```

Now we "combine" these chunks:  `3 * 7 = 21`.

I am pretty sure you already see that the second list in such a scenario would result in `25`; as such different operations in the accumulator and combiner can result in wrong results.

Comment: I only said the combiner and accumulator can be the same, not that I can **always** use the accumulator as combiner.

Comment: @EugenCovaci didn't you answer your question yourself with the edit? 1) of course you can use `stream.reduce(id, op, op);` if you are reducing to the same type that the Stream has (this is what happens internally when you do `stream.reduce(id, op);` anyway). 2) if you want to reduce to a _different_ type than the Stream has, those 2 will be different.

Comment: @EugenCovaci or do you mean "different" in the sense that they perform different operations? like one does a `sum`, the other does a `multiply`?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that they perform different operations.

Comment: @EugenCovaci then is such a case this question is _only_ interesting if _both_ the `accumulator` and `combiner` are associative, but entail a different operation (`sum` and `multiply` for example). Working on an edit... will ping when done.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest. Actually, the associativity is a required property for reduction.

Comment: I think `(x, y) -> x + y.length()` is not associative, it breaks the reduction contract.

Comment: @EugenCovaci can you _prove_ that? Is that any different than : `Stream.of("one", "two").map(String::length).reduce(0, Integer::sum)`?

Comment: I think you need to read @Eugene's code snippet example again. What _type_ is the identity being passed to reduce? And hence what _type_ is `x` in `(x, y) -> x + y.length()`?

Comment: Right, my example was wrong. The question is: how can the associativity be formulated for the accumulator?

Comment: `(a op b) op c == a op (b op c)` doesn't make sense since `b` has to be String from `(a op b)` and int from `(b op c)`

Comment: Indeed, I see no need for the accumulator to be associative - it doesn't even need to be an operator. It does has to be _commutative_ in the second argument (i.e. `op(op(a, b), c) === op(op(a, c), b)`.

Comment: From the documentation: accumulator – an associative, non-interfering, stateless function for incorporating an additional element into a result

Comment: I would assume they meant to say commutative there. Otherwise, I literally don't know what they mean.

Comment: @user31601 it _might_ have to do with the fact that internally combiner is the same as the accumulator, when you use `reduce(Identity, accumulator)`.

Comment: Yes - I can see that associativity would be required for the 2-argument overload, because the combiner _does_ need to be associative.

Comment: @user31601 exactly! as such document it as such and move on, probably much more simple at the implementation side.

Comment: I actually think this a case of copy-paste laziness on the part of the API developers. The 3 argument overload won't delegate to the 2-argument overload (more likely the other way round), so there's absolutely no reason why the accumulator needs to be associative in the 3-arg overload. Indeed, when `T` and `U` are different, the concept of associativity doesn't even make sense.