# Consumer or Function for builder

Tags: java, builder, method-reference

I wrote a builder to set some configurations. One of the builder's method is `edit(BusinessObject)`. Now I got the requirement which leads to the same config except replacing this method by `copy(BusinessObject)`. So the current implementation would be:

```
public Config editObject(BusinessObject object) {
    return new ConfigBuilder()
        .config1(p1)
        .config2(p2)
        .config3(p3)
        ...
        .edit(object)
        .build();
}

public Config copyObject(BusinessObject object) {
    return new ConfigBuilder()
        .config1(p1)
        .config2(p2)
        .config3(p3)
        ...
        .copy(object)
        .build();
}

class ConfigBuilder {

    ConfigBuilder edit(BusinessObject o) {
        // prepare some settings
        return this;
    }

    ConfigBuilder copy(BusinessObject o) {
        // prepare some other settings
        return this;
    }
}
```

To avoid duplicated code (except this one line everything else is the same) I want to extract it to a new method with an additional parameter like `Function<BusinessObject, ConfigBuilder> prepare`.

But I'm stuck how to solve it. The builder instance will be created outside of `editObject`/`copyObject`'s scope so `editOrCopy(object, ConfigBuilder::copy)` does not work since this method is not static.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution but I'm not very happy with this. I added a static version of the methods with a builder parameter (Thanks to **Holger**: now I'm happy, there is no need of the static methods):

```
class ConfigBuilder

    ConfigBuilder edit(BusinessObject o) {
        // prepare some settings
        return this;
    }

    ConfigBuilder copy(BusinessObject o) {
        // prepare some other settings
        return this;
    }
}
```

Now I can pass the method reference to the newly created method:

```
private Config modifyObject(BusinessObject object, BiFunction<ConfigBuilder, BusinessObject, ConfigBuilder> modify) {
    return modify.apply(new ConfigBuilder(), object)
        .config1(p1)
        .config2(p2)
        .config3(p3)
        ...
        .build();
}
```

The invokation is as mentioned in the question

```
public Config editObject(BusinessObject object) {
    return modifyObject(object, ConfigBuilder::edit);
}

public Config copyObject(BusinessObject object) {
    return modifyObject(object, ConfigBuilder::copy);
}
```

Comment: The `static` methods are obsolete. Just try what happens when you replace `ConfigBuilder::editStatic` with `ConfigBuilder::edit`, resp. replace `ConfigBuilder::copyStatic` with `ConfigBuilder::copy`. See also [What's the difference between instance method reference types in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22516331/2711488)…

Comment: Thanks @Holger. I thought I tried it but I think it was with `Function<BusinessObject, ConfigBuilder>` so I got the compiler error

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason passing a function in here.  Simply extracting common code out should already save your duplicated code. And, imho, it is easier to ready and to understand

```
private ConfigBuilder commonBuilder() {
    return new ConfigBuilder()
        .config1(p1)
        .config2(p2)
        .config3(p3);
}

public Config editObject(BusinessObject object) {
    return commonBuilder().edit(object).build();
}

public Config copyObject(BusinessObject object) {
    return commonBuilder().copy(object).build();
}
```

Comment: For the given information it would work. But in my code I do not use `return new ConfigBuilder()...build()` but I store it in a variable because there is some omitted code below (my fault).